# Express.js - Cannot Set Headers with exported function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mocha.js

Learning how to do testing with Express with using *Mocha*, *Chai*, *Chai-HTTP* plugin, and *MongoDB* with Mongoose. I have a test to purposely detect if MongoDB will send back an error from trying to find a document using a faulty `_id` value (too short).

I noticed that part of my code is repeating around my other Express routes, and want to reuse it for other routes so I exported it from another module, but now I get this:

`Uncaught Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Not sure why I am getting this error. If I have the same code, as the exported function, inside the route code it works fine, but exported it just complains.

Here is the code:

**test/route/example.test.js** Snippit

```js
it('Bad request with a too short ID string (12 characters minimum)', () => {
    // /api/v1/example is the endpoint
    // /blah is the param
    chai.request(app).get('/api/v1/example/blah').end((err, res) => {
       // Insert all the nice assert stuff. :) 
    });
});
```

**route/example.js** Snippit

```js
// Packages
const router = require('express').Router();

// Models (Mongoose Schemas)
const Example = require('../models/example.model');

// Helpers
const { foundMongoError } = require('../helpers/routes');

// -----Snipped-----

router.route('/:exampleId').get((req, res) => {
    // Retrieve the exampleId parameter.
    const exampleId = req.params.exampleId;

    Example.findById(exampleId, (mongoError, mongoResponse) => {
        foundMongoError(mongoError, res); // Having an issue

        // If I have the same code that makes up foundMongoError inside here, no issues, 
        // but it will no longer be DRY.

        // Check if any responses from MongoDB
        if(mongoResponse) {
            res.status(200).json(mongoResponse);
        } else {
            return res.status(404).json({
                errorCode: 404,
                errorCodeMessage: 'Not Found',
                errorMessage: `Unable to find example with id: ${exampleId}.`
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**helpers/routes.js**

```js
const foundMongoError = (mongoError, res) => {
    if(mongoError) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            errorCode: 400,
            errorCodeMessage: 'Bad Request',
            errorMessage: mongoError.message
        });
    }
};

module.exports = {
    foundMongoError
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That just means you send and response `res` twice back. The first time you send it back at here:

```
    if(mongoError) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            errorCode: 400,
            errorCodeMessage: 'Bad Request',
            errorMessage: mongoError.message
        });
    }
```

You sended an response back but the function still continue its work, that means the function moves on till here then:

```
    if(mongoResponse) {
        res.status(200).json(mongoResponse);
    } else {
        return res.status(404).json({
            errorCode: 404,
            errorCodeMessage: 'Not Found',
            errorMessage: `Unable to find example with id: ${exampleId}.`
        });
    }
```

Here happens the second response, and here you get the error.

I would rewrite the code like this:

Instead of returning the response, you return an `true` that means there is an error, otherwise `false` :

```
const foundMongoError = (mongoError, res) => {
    if(mongoError) {
        res.status(400).json({
            errorCode: 400,
            errorCodeMessage: 'Bad Request',
            errorMessage: mongoError.message
        });
    return true;
    }
    return false;
};

module.exports = {
    foundMongoError
};
```

Then you can write it like this:

```
if(foundMongoError(mongoError, res)) return;
```

The `return` will stop the function to execute the rest of the code

Comment: After a few seconds typing this question I realized I needed to return the response from the routes file, yet I like your approach more than what I was trying to do. Thanks!